# JPA - variables double are being rounded

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a model entity like this:

```
    @Entity
public class Produtos{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    private String nome;
    
    private Long quantidade;
    
    private boolean frete;
    
    private Double precoNovo;
    
    private Double precoAntigo;
    
    private boolean promocao;
    
    private boolean variacaoCor;
    
    private String[] cores;
    
    private String corUnica;
}
```

when i use (private Double precoAntigo) to save the product price, the spring rounds the value, ex: 2500.50 to 2500, how do I disable this option?

Comment: What is the DB type for the Double columns?

Comment: DO.NOT.EVER.USE.DOUBLE.FOR.PRICES.USE.BIGDECIMAL

Comment: @crizzis I changed that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#precision()
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#scale()

```
@Column(scale=2)
private Double precoNovo;

@Column(scale=2)
private Double precoAntigo;
```